# Promise is in pending while in each array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, es6-promise, cloudinary

I want execute promise in array of object and replace path value from array with promise response in same array i was trying below code:

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary')
const cloudinaryConfig = require('../configs/cloudConfig.json')

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: cloudinaryConfig.cloud_name,
    api_key: cloudinaryConfig.api_key,
    api_secret: cloudinaryConfig.api_secret
})

fileArray = [
  {
    fieldname: 'productThumbImage',
    originalname: 'Boyka.png',
    path: '/home/rahul/MaxDigiAssignment/mxNodeEcommerce/mx-ecommercenode/upload/product/1589983049420.png'
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'productPhoto',
    originalname: 'Code.png',
    filename: '1589983049436.png',
    path: '/home/rahul/MaxDigiAssignment/mxNodeEcommerce/mx-ecommercenode/upload/product/1589983049436.png'
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'productPhoto',
    originalname: 'Boyka.png',
    filename: '1589983049438.png',
    path: '/home/rahul/MaxDigiAssignment/mxNodeEcommerce/mx-ecommercenode/upload/product/1589983049438.png'
  }
]

 const files =  imgs.map(async (img)=>{
        let path = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(img.path)
        return {
            ...img,
            filePath: path.url
        }
    })

console.log('files 11///  ',await files);
```

but i am getting error promise  {  }

I want to execute this promise in each object and get response then
my expected array like below :

```
[
  {
    fieldname: 'productThumbImage',
    originalname: 'Boyka.png',
    path:'http://res.cloudinary.com/deqpxepbs/image/upload/v1589982424/ywfetodkvyadmdqjof1i.png'
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'productPhoto',
    originalname: 'Code.png',
    filename: '1589983049436.png',
    path:'http://res.cloudinary.com/deqpxepbs/image/upload/v1589982424/desb18dgungva5y8apbv.png'
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'productPhoto',
    originalname: 'Boyka.png',
    filename: '1589983049438.png',
    path:'http://res.cloudinary.com/deqpxepbs/image/upload/v1589982424/ugud4flh7gfl3ymyh0xx.png'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`files` will be an array of promises, it isnt a single promise. You should:

```
console.log('files 11///  ',await Promise.all(files));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

- `map` your array of images to an array of `Promise`s
- `await` all your `Promise`s and get their results as an array of paths/URLs
- `map` the array of paths to an array of objects.

```js
const getNewFiles = async (imgs) => {
    const promises = imgs.map(img => {
        return cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(img.path)
    })

    const paths = await Promise.all(promises)
    /* If you're using Node.js version 12 or more recent, a better
       alternative to `Promise.all` is `Promise.allSettled` */
    // const paths = await Promise.allSettled(promises)

    const newFiles = paths.map((path, index) => {
        return {
            ...imgs[index],
            path: path.url
        }
    })

    return newFiles
}

// You can now just pass your `fileArray` to this function as below
const files = await getNewFiles(fileArray)
console.log(files)
```